# How to share form validation between 2 Angular components

Tags: angular

I have components with forms for add/edit functionality. The form fields for both Add and Edit are identical and thus I would like to reuse my form validation in each. I have the following validation setup in my Add class I am exporting:

```
export class AddCarriersComponent implements OnInit {

  addCarrierForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.addCarrierForm = this.fb.group({
      carrierName:                   ['', Validators.required],
      contactNumber:                 ['', Validators.required],
      addressLineOne:                ['', Validators.required],
      addressLineTwo:                [''],
      city:                          ['', Validators.required],
      state:                         ['', Validators.required],
      county:                        ['', Validators.required],
      zip:                           ['', Validators.required],
      contactName:                   ['', Validators.required],
      contactEmail:                  ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      phone:                         [''],
      mobile:                        ['', Validators.required],
      carrierAcceptanceDays:         [''],
      rateRoundingOptions:           ['', Validators.required],
      subscriptionPlanName:          ['', Validators.required],
      subscriptionPlanDuration:      ['', Validators.required],
      subscriptionPlanEffectiveDate: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

How can I share these validation requirements with my Edit component?

Comment: create a common service put your function in it and Inject your common service to your components where you want to use this validation function

Comment: Would I just need to import the service in each component?

Comment: If they are identical, you could use the same form, for both edit and add, and add pass the form callback as input to the component. But also trichetriche solution is really good, because you are creating you form model and can eventually reuse it for HTTP calls, etc.

Comment: you mean inject? yes you have to to Inject the service in your components and call it through the function name like :

    this.commonService.checkValidation(data);

Answer (score 3):

Create a class :

```
export class Carrier {
  name: string;
  // etc. 

  toFormGroup() {
    return {
      name: [this.name, Validators.required],
      // etc. 
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can manage it in your components :

```
carrier = new Carrier();
form = this.formBuilder.group(this.carrier.toFormGroup());
```

This allows you to centralize all of your object logic into a single class. For instance, you could add a `persist()` method that will make an HTTP call to your backend, or things like that.

Comment: Would that class exist in my root module for the Carrier object or a new component?

Comment: That would be a new file, `Carrier.ts`, like you would do in any typed language. That's not an Angular component, in fact that's uncorrelated from Angular. It's simply a Typescript class !

Comment: @noclist and if you already have a carrier class, then simply add the method to it !